# How to add more than one component to MainFrame contents

Tags: swing, scala

I want to make window with few panels. I can append one to MainFrame's contents:
import swing._

```
class View(model:Model) extends MainFrame {
  title = "app"

  val parameters = new FlowPanel() {
    contents += new Label("Tempo: ")
    contents += new ComboBox(Seq("80", "100", "120", "140"))
    contents += new Label("Metric: ")
    contents += new Label("Note: ")
  }

  contents = parameters
}
```

but when I try to append another:

```
    class View(model:Model) extends MainFrame {
      title = "app"

      val parameters = new FlowPanel() {
        contents += new Label("Tempo: ")
        contents += new ComboBox(Seq("80", "100", "120", "140"))
        contents += new Label("Metric: ")
        contents += new Label("Note: ")
      }

      val controls = new FlowPanel() {
        contents += new Button( "klop" ) 
      }

      contents = parameters
      contents += controls
    }
```

it doesn't works:

```
src/View.scala:40: error: type mismatch;
 found   : scala.swing.FlowPanel
 required: String
  contents += controls
              ^
one error found
Error: Build failed.
```

How should I do that? I tried with a Container but I don't know how to use it properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`MainFrame`, as you have discovered, can contain only one thing.

Therefore, you need to place both `parameters` and `controls` into some container that is designed to lay out multiple other containers.  You already used a `FlowPanel` for this--you could do so again.  Alternatively, a `BoxPanel` in direction `Orientation.Vertical` is probably more what you had in mind.

So you add the other containers to that `BoxPanel`, and then set the `BoxPanel` as `MainFrame`'s contents.